# Transform.position returns 0 0 0 while GameObject is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with unity's transform.position while my GameObject is moving.(I need to know transform.position so I can change the GameObject's velocity)... The first time around it works perfectly fine.... but then it stops working the second time around (in other words, returning 0 0 0).

Thanks in advance!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class CharacterMove : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Stack<Vector3Int> path;
    List<Vector3Int> rev;



    int xDir;
    int yDir;

    [SerializeField]
    int speed = 5;

    [SerializeField]
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    Vector3Int currentGoal;
    Vector3Int finalGoal;



    [SerializeField]
    Tilemap tilemap;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rev = new List<Vector3Int>();
        path = new Stack<Vector3Int>();
        // rigidbody2D.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    } 

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      
       
        

        if ((path.Count > 0 || rev.Count > 0) && isOnDestination(currentGoal))
        {

            if (rev.Count == 0)
            {
                while (path.Count > 0)
                {
                   
                    rev.Add(path.Pop());
                }
                finalGoal = rev[rev.Count - 1];
            }


            
            Debug.Log(rev[0]);
            currentGoal = rev[0];
            rev.RemoveAt(0);
            calcXDir(currentGoal.x,Mathf.FloorToInt(transform.position.x));
            calcYDir(currentGoal.y,Mathf.FloorToInt(transform.position.y));
            setMovement();
           
            




        } else if (rev.Count == 0 && isOnDestination(finalGoal))
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }

   public void setMovement()
    {
        float x = xDir * speed;
        float y = yDir * speed;
        
        rigidbody2D.velocity =  Vector2.zero;
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(x, y);
    }

    public void calcXDir(int nodeX, int thisX)
    {
        Debug.Log("x : " + nodeX + " x : " + thisX);
        if (nodeX > thisX)
        {
            xDir = 1;
        }
        else if (nodeX < thisX)
        {
            xDir = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            xDir = 0;
        }
    }

    public void calcYDir(int nodeY,int thisY)
    {
        Debug.Log("y : " + nodeY + " y : " + thisY);
        if (nodeY > thisY)
        {
            yDir = 1;
        }
        else if (nodeY < thisY)
        {
            yDir = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            yDir = 0;
        }
   
    }

    public bool isOnDestination(Vector3Int destination)
    {
        
        Vector3 vector = rigidbody2D.transform.position;
        Vector3Int vector3int = new Vector3Int(Mathf.FloorToInt(vector.x), Mathf.FloorToInt(vector.y),
            Mathf.FloorToInt(transform.position.z));

 
        if (tilemap.GetTile(vector3int) == 
            tilemap.GetTile(destination))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Is the game object a child of something else moving?

Comment: @BugFinder hmm not really

Comment: When are you pushing something to the `path` stack?